# Locally Integrated Menu (LIM) on GNOME

Tags: gnome, settings

Is there any GNOME extension (or any way) that enable LIM (as we have in Unity)?

For instance: In UNITY we have the title bar as follows:

[image: Unity Title Bar]

I would like to have this in GNOME.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: I would love a LIM rather than a Globally Integrated Menu (GIM) in Gnome

Comment: Yes, the question need a clarification with base on the Greg comment.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that in Gnome this is not possible. Now Wayland is in development and it's possible that the Wayland project doesn't include this feature.

It's really sad that Ubuntu is leaving Unity because one of the more interesting features (personal opinion) of Unity is the integrated app menu.

Last week OMG Ubuntu announced that Lester Carballo wouldn't work anymore on Global Menu Extension: [GNOME Global Menu Extension ‘Discontinued For the Moment’](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/gnome-global-menu-extension-discontinued).

Comment: The article you linked to says the extension still works fine in Xorg sessions, just not in Wayland. So, I don't understand why your answer says "this is not possible"

Comment: LIM: Locally Integrated Menus, is not the same as GIM: Global Integrated Menus.